# Setting up Tiles with Spring for unprotected resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles, apache-tiles

I am having problems setting up tiles with a spring mvc in an existing application. Here is my setup info:

- All my jsps are under /project/* directory.  I am trying to access
  JSPs (help files etc.) via static links in other JSPs (like `<a
  href="tilesTest.jsp">Tiles Test</a>`). 
  **I do not have any controllers for these JSPs, and do not want to write controllers for this specific use case (I have tested that it works with controllers), so plz do not suggest writing controllers.**

Here are my configurations:

**spring-mvc-context.xml entries:**

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring/tiles-def.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">   
     <!-- <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/> -->
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
</bean>
```

**tiles-def.xml entry:**

```
 <definition name="tilesTest" template="/tilesTest.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="TITLE for TEST-TILES JSP"/>
    <put-attribute name="leftMenu" value="MY LEFT MENU"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="SOME BODY"/>        
</definition>
```

**tilesTest.jsp located under /projectWarName/tilesTest.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<html>
    <head>Tiles Test Page</head>
    <title><tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title>
    <body>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error when i try to access my jsp (either through a link from another jsp, or directly via the browser). Can someone plz review my configuration and let me know what's wrong?

```
root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.tiles.template.DefaultAttributeResolver.computeAttribute(DefaultAttributeResolver.java:42)
    org.apache.tiles.template.GetAsStringModel.resolveAttribute(GetAsStringModel.java:178)
    org.apache.tiles.template.GetAsStringModel.start(GetAsStringModel.java:95)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.GetAsStringTag.doTag(GetAsStringTag.java:306)
    org.apache.jsp.tilesTest_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005fgetAsString_005f0(tilesTest_jsp.java:128)
    org.apache.jsp.tilesTest_jsp._jspService(tilesTest_jsp.java:82)
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't you always need to pass the request through the `DispatcherServlet` else the tiles view resolving stuff isn't going to work. Letting people access your JSPs directly is also a bit dangerous, put them in your `WEB-INF` directory and register [view controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) for those views. Next to that use the `TilesViewResolver` instead of the `UrlBasedViewResolver`.

Comment: I have DispatcherServlet configured for all requests, i did not post it here for the sake of brevity. I know it's a better practice to put JSPs under WEB-INF directory, but as i mentioned some of these are help files etc.I know it works if i register view controllers, but my question is how to do it without registering the view controllers.

Comment: It won't work as you need tiles to process the files, so you need either the `DispatcherServlet` delegate that to a `ViewResolver` or need to setup tiles to work outside the realm of the `DispatcherServlet`. Either way you need to pass the request to/through tiles. In your case the easiest way is to just let the `DispatcherServlet` handle it correctly...